# In TestCafe is there a way to know if the test passed or failed in after hook?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, hook, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to mark tests as pass/failed through a rest API (Zephyr) while my testcafe tests are running.  I was wondering if it's possible in the **after** or **afterEach** hook to know if the test passed/failed so that I can run some script based on the result.

Something like:

```js
test(...)
.after(async t => {
  if(testFailed === true) { callApi('my test failed'); }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two ways in which to solve your task. First, do not subscribe to the `after` hook, but create your own `reporter` or modify the existing `reporter`. Please refer to the following article: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/#implementing-the-reporter
 
The most interesting method there is `reportTestDone` because it accepts `errs` as a parameter, so you can add your custom logic there.

The second approach is using [sharing variables between hooks and test code](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#sharing-variables-between-fixture-hooks-and-test-code)

You can write your test in the following manner:

```
test(`test`, async t => {
    await t.click('#non-existing-element');

    t.ctx.passed = true;
}).after(async t => {
    if (t.ctx.passed)
        throw new Error('not passed');
});
```

Here I am using the shared `passed` variable between the test code and hook. If the test fails, the variable will not be set to true, and I'll get an error in the `after` hook.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing (the custom reporter).  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be determined from the test controller, which has more information nested within it that is only visible at run time. An array containing all the errors thrown in the test is available as follows

```
t.testRun.errs
```

If the array is populated, then the test has failed.

Comment: This is an undocumented internal API, but it does work.