# Can testcafe afterEach() fixture calls know whether the test passed or not?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

My Fixture looks like this:

```
fixture`Admitted: Happy Path`
  .page(environment.admitted)
  .requestHooks(logger)
  .afterEach(logErrors);
```

`logErrors` logs all the API errors from that test, however I would only like to log them if the test failed.  Is there a way to tell if the test that just finished succeeded in `fixture.afterEach()`?

Answer (score 4):

I've provided several approaches to solve this issue in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656728/in-testcafe-is-there-a-way-to-know-if-the-test-passed-or-failed-in-after-hook).
Please refer to it.